# Set y position for label - ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have the below `df`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

# dummy data
df <- data.table(revenue = rnorm(1e4, mean = 100, sd = 1)); df

         revenue
    1: 100.01769
    2:  98.31862
    3:  99.78464
    4: 100.17670
    5:  99.31678
   ---          
 9996:  99.47635
 9997:  98.27383
 9998:  99.48378
 9999: 100.06227
10000:  99.13972
```

and that I plot a histogram with a `vline` denoting the mean

```
# mean of x axis
x <- df[, mean(revenue)]

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = revenue)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..) / sum(..count..))) + # turn count into %
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = x), col = 'red', size = 1)
```

[image]

The above is fine. However, when trying to add a label showing the mean, I am unsure what to enter for `y` in `geom_label(aes(x = x, y = ?)...`:

```
# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = revenue)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..) / sum(..count..))) + # turn count into %
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = x), col = 'red', size = 1) +
  geom_label(aes(x = x, y = ?)
             , label = x
             )
```

I have tried small numbers such as 0.025 (after looking at the density from the previous plot) but then R gets stuck and creating the plot and never finishes. Say, I'd like to position the numeric label at where y axis = 0, then what value should I put into `y =` ?
Thank you

Comment: Remove `aes()` from `geom_label`, you are plotting constants, not a data.table variables . Make `y=0`. Use `hjust` and `vjust` to position the label relative to (the constants) `x`, `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `aes()` from `geom_label`, you are plotting constants, not a data.table variables . To plot where the y axis is zero, well, make `y = 0`.

Use `hjust` and `vjust` to position the label relative to (the constants) `x`, `y`. From the documentation:

> Alignment
> You can modify text alignment with the vjust and hjust aesthetics. These can either be a number between 0 (right/bottom) and 1 (top/left) or a character ("left", "middle", "right", "bottom", "center", "top"). There are two special alignments: "inward" and "outward". Inward always aligns text towards the center, and outward aligns it away from the center.

And it does take time. Once again from the documentation, my emphasis:

> geom_label()
> Currently geom_label() does not support the check_overlap argument or the angle aesthetic. **Also, it is considerably slower than geom_text()**. The fill aesthetic controls the background colour of the label.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#library(data.table)

# dummy data
df <- data.frame(revenue = rnorm(1e4, mean = 100, sd = 1))

xbar <- mean(df$revenue)

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = revenue)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..) / sum(..count..)), bins = 30) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = xbar), col = 'red', size = 1) +
  geom_label(x = xbar, y = 0, label = round(xbar, 2), 
            hjust = -0.5, vjust = 1, 
            fill = "white", color = "black")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, Rui
geom_label indeed is slow. I am trying `geom_text` but when trying `geom_text(label = xbar , hjust = 0)` I get the error `Error in check_required_aesthetics():
! geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: y`

Comment: I have resorted to using `annotate("text", x=x, y=.025, label= round(x, 1), size = 6)` instead. But welcome other methods that are quicker than `geom_label` as it is prohibitively slow (approx 60 secs to produce a graph)

Comment: @SweepyDodo `geom_text` doesn't have a `fill` aesthetic. Remove it *keeping everything else* as I posted for `geom_label` and it should work. (It works with me.) Also, I forgot to say in the answer but I have used `data.frame` to avoid loading another package, no other special reason.

Comment: I mean it does work but takes around 60 seconds to create the graph. Does it take that long for you, Rui?

Comment: @SweepyDodo I haven't timed it but it takes a long time, `geom_text` is much faster.

Comment: Try `annotate(geom = "label")` instead.